# Сортировка двумерного массива

Tags: c, массивы, c++builder

Вот программа - для ввода двумерного массива, компилятор мне выдает `int main(){` как ошибку. В чем может быть проблема? И еще как прописать сортировку столбцов по убыванию?

```
int main()
{
    int a[i][j];
    int row, col;
    int i,j;

    printf("Enter size of matrix: n");
    scanf("%d  %d", &row, &col);

    for (i = 0; i < col; i++)
    {
    for (j = 0; j < row; j++)
      {
        a[i][j] = (int) rand() % 100;

    printf("%2d", a[i][j]);
}

printf("n");
}
```

}

Comment: При создании вопроса, указывайте в метках используемый язык программирования.

Comment: c++ пишется все через Borland C++ Builder 6 консольное приложение

Comment: кажется еще и '{' где то одну потеряли

Comment: Вот это что такое?

       int a[i][j];

Откуда компилятор знает эти i и j?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void View(int **arr, int row, int col) {
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            printf("%3d", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    int row, col;
    printf("Enter size of matrix:");
    scanf("%d  %d", &row, &col);

    // Выделение памяти под массив
    int **arr = (int **)malloc(row * sizeof(int *));
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        arr[i] = (int *)malloc(col * sizeof(int));

    // Присваивание случайных значений
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = (int) rand() % 100;
        }
    }

    // Отобразить исходный массив
    View(arr, row, col);

    // Сортировка выбором столбцов по убыванию
    int MinRow, Temp;
    for (int NumCol = 0; NumCol < col; NumCol++) {
        for (int NumRow = 0; NumRow < row - 1; NumRow++) { 
            MinRow = NumRow;
            for (int j = NumRow + 1; j < row; j++)
                if (arr[j][NumCol] > arr[MinRow][NumCol])
                   MinRow = j;
            Temp = arr[NumRow][NumCol];
            arr[NumRow][NumCol] = arr[MinRow][NumCol]; 
            arr[MinRow][NumCol] = Temp;
        }
    }

    // Вывод отсортированного массива
    printf("\n");
    View(arr, row, col);

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В коде программы есть несоответствие между открывающими и закрывающими скобками: число открывающих меньше, чем число закрывающих. Необходимо привести их в соответствии.

Сортировки здесь нет вообще: есть только заполнение таблицы случайными значениями. Причем слабо понятно, как изначально размещается память под таблицу. Вообще [алгоритмов сортировки](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C0%EB%E3%EE%F0%E8%F2%EC_%F1%EE%F0%F2%E8%F0%EE%E2%EA%E8) много - выбирайте на любой вкус.

Comment: как понять "слабо понятно, как изначально размещается память под таблицу"? это не динамический массив.

Answer (score 0):

У второго цикла (по j) отсутствует открывающая блок скобка.

Comment: теперь еще больше ошибок стало, а то одна была связанная с int main(){